# How can I see the places a function is being called in vim?

Tags: perl, vim, plugins

I have been using vim and ctags for going over Perl files.
I was wondering the following:
Is there a way/plugin I can use so that I can press a key combination and be able to see all the places a function is called (as easily as I can jump to the definition of a function or view the list of all functions with the same name in all files of my project with ctags)?
I have read about cscope but I am not sure if it is usable for Perl or there is a solution for scripting languages.

Comment: A few seconds on google show perl is supported by cscope. Try it before ruling it out.

Comment: @romainl:I could not find any specific example for Perl so I am not sure if it would work or if it would break my ctags

Comment: Can't you simply try it?

Comment: @romainl:Problem is, if I "break" my set up, I am not sure if I can easily fix it. I am not an advanced user in either vim or linux.

Comment: You won't break anything. Install cscope, read its manual and `:h cscope` and try a few things.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
" Lists lines containing the word under the cursor. Type the line number
" followed by <CR> to jump to the corresponding line.
nnoremap [I [I:
xnoremap [I "vy:<C-u>ilist /<C-r>v<CR>:

" Same as above but for 'defines'
nnoremap [D [D:
xnoremap [D "vy:<C-u>dlist /<C-r>v<CR>:
```

Then position the cursor under a word and type `[I` or `[D`.